# Need help filtering out incomplete entries in a .csv [Python]

Tags: python, csv, filter

I have a set of data points, which look like this:

ID  70014   1940    1   1   26.8    1   Y

ID  70014   1940    1   2   29.8    1   Y

ID  70014   1940    1   3   34.3    1   Y

ID  70014   1940    1   4   35.7    1   Y

ID  70014   1940    1   5   34.1    1   Y

but some of the entries have missing values, like the ones below:

ID  70014   1940    6   30
ID  70014   1940    7   1   14  1   N

I need to use the def function to set the parameters for legit entries and then filter them out, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about that. I'm getting confused about where it should be located in my code, I'm fairly certain I know how to describe the parameters, but not how to connect this code to the rest of my program.

If I've left anything out, let me know, I'm happy to describe the issue more thoroughly :)

Cheers.

Comment: @greole I'm basically trying to use if functions to declare when an entry should come up as False, eg:

dec accept_entry(entry)  
    if (column3 == "")  
        return False  
    if (column7 != "Y")  
        return False  
    return True  
  
but I sorta get stuck here, and don't know how to make it skip a False entry.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you just post the code and the error you got so far.

Comment: You've stated that lines like these: `ID 70014 1940 7 1 14 1 N` are missing values. However, it's not. It has the right amount of values (8). Am I missing something wrong?

Comment: One of the parameters is that the 8th column be a Y. Anything else is False. Sorry, I should have mentioned there are other parameters, the number one is just the first example that came to mind...  

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngkp7m71x4msdqw/Temperature%20Code.py?dl=0

Comment: Yes you could place the *relevant* parts of the code directly in your question

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could do is splitting the string and count if there are enough fields:

```
def is_valid_ID(Id):
   if len(Id.split()) == 8:
       return True
   else:
       return False

 >>>is_Valid_Id("ID 70014 1940 1 1 26.8 1 Y")
 True
 >>>is_Valid_Id("ID 70014 1940 1 1 26.8 1")
 False
```

However, this wont check if the individual elements are valid (You could use regexps for that).

Or the same thing in more compact notation

```
def is_valid_ID(Id):
    return (True if len(Id.split()) == 8 else False)
```

If you want to use regexps you could try

```
 import re

 def accept_entry(entry):
     try:
         return re.search("ID [0-9]{5} [0-9]{4} [0-9] [0-9] [0-9.]* [0-9] Y",entry).group()
     except:
         return False
```

Comment: Thanks very much  

Should the def come inside the 'for entry'loop? I've run the code as is, with the def at the bottom, and python's telling me the variable's 'not defined' yet.

Comment: Just before your `if __name__ == "__main__"` line

Comment: Awesome, You helped me get it working the way it should. I was having trouble with some of the relevant syntax it seems, and your post made it click in my head what I was doing wrong, thanks a million!

Comment: No need for thanking me, if a solution worked for you accepting the answer is the best thing to do ;)